# jQuery validator using previous value after bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, customvalidator

I'm using a bootstrap datepicker that is initialised like so...

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    language: "en-GB",
    startDate: "01/01/1900",
    endDate: "31/12/2200",
    autoclose: true,
    forceParse: false
});
```

Then I have a custom jQuery validator which is...

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("futuredaterequired", function (value, element, params) {
        //Validation code here
    });
});
```

However, once I've make a selection from the datepicker the `value` in the validator method is the previous value that was selected in the datepicker.  Not the newly selected value.

So I tried using `element` to get the value again, however that also returns the previous value of the datepicker.  If I put a `setTimeOut` on the entire method then the `value` is correct, However the timeout causes other issues.

Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution to this I have now found is...

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    language: "en-GB",
    startDate: "01/01/1900",
    endDate: "31/12/2200",
    autoclose: true,
    forceParse: false
})
.on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

This way, the jQuery validation is run after the actual value has been changed in the input.

The method still runs on the initial selection of a date and still uses the previous date value.  However when it runs a 2nd time on `changeDate` it uses the correct value.

Not ideal... but it works.  If you have any better solutions, please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug in BSDP where it fires an event before updating, which is picked up by the validation